# Please suggest Web API architecture interact with MVC and Android

Tags: android, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Can some one suggest me the best approach to prepare the architecture for Web API + MVC + Android + SQL server. Since I am new in Web Api, unable to find best approach to prepare this. 
Requirement is same functionality should from both MVC and Android application.

**Edited**
[image]

Comment: Anyone have idea ? please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider Web API to be a core functionality layer. For example, if you are building shopping applications it will have "GetProducts" functionality which will return a JSON result set of the products. This Web API talks to SQL Server for the "Product Data".

Consider the MVC application and the Android application to be the clients which consume the Web API layer. For example if you you need a web page which displays all the products, you would build a MVC controller/method which will call the Web API "GetProducts" to get products list and then display it. Similarly, in the Android application if you need a screen which displays all the products data, then it will call the Web Api "GetProducts" and display the data on the screen.

Comment: Thanks Sunil. I have added the architecture as you suggested. is this right architecture you meant ? How to identify request is from android app or from mvc view in web api controller. accordingly if it is from mvc action then web api method should return core class say customer, and if it is from android then it should return json. How to tackle response from WebAPI based on request comes from ?

Comment: Make a service layer(Class library project) which exposes business logic or just just calls the repository layer. It will have functions like `public Customer GetCustomer()`. The MVC controller can call this service layer to get the `Customer` object which can be used in the View. The Web Api controller can also call this service layer to get the same `Customer` object, but then it will return `Customer` as JSON to the caller, in your case the Android application.